# Flexmojos compatibility with Flex SDK to 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flexmojos

I was working on a project with flexmojos 3.9 and Flex 4.0.
I decided to upgrafe my version of the flex SDK to 4.5 but I have the followin problems:

1- Maven Message: [FATAL ERROR] org.sonatype.flexmojos.optimizer.OptimizerMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms

2- Stack trace: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:flex2.compiler.common.Configuration.setKeepDebugOpcodes(Z)V

Regards,

Fadi

Comment: Flexmojos 3.9 works fine with Flex 4.5. Please post your Maven POM and relevant configuration settings for Flexmojos and I can supply an answer.

Answer (score 1):

FlexMojos 3.9 is extremely outdated and you should look into 4.0-RC1 from https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/maven-sites/flexmojos/

Comment: Yeah that means I need maven 3.X.X and currently my company use maven 2.X.X. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Then make them update it?  I mean, maven 2 is outdated as well :P